# Identification of odd jellyfish-like creature in the Mediterranean

Tags: species-identification, invertebrates

My parents encountered this unknown creature on a beach in Karpathos, Greece.

None of the locals have seen it before, it may be a species that has moved further north due to ocean warming.

Any ideas what it is?

[image: Unknown jellyfish-like creature]

Comment: @tyersome - Thank you for migrating to the proper page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems to be a "Hula skirt siphonophore" - *Physophora hydrostatica*

> Physophora hydrostatica, also known as hula skirt siphonophore, is a
> species of siphonophores in the family Physophoridae.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0oS2b.png)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physophora_hydrostatica

[image]

Comment: Nicely done. Distribution is in the Mediterranean and much of the Atlantic, so that fits. There are some nice photos of it [here](http://www.seawater.no/fauna/cnidaria/hydrostatica.html)